# Constant identifier modification in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const float PIE=3.1415926535; 

    float *pie=const_cast<float*>(&PIE);

    *pie=7.9;   
    cout<<"float:"<<PIE<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So What I want do here is to modify const PIE by casting its adress to a non const pointer and then modify PIE through this pointer.
I don't know why Its not working or i am wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

"Attempting to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior."  This could be a program crash (trying to modify read-only memory), unexpected results, or no effect at all.  In this case the value of the `PIE` constant is probably being output directly (rather than thru the variable) when compiled so your attempt to change the value doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
let me sure about one thing here.
During compilation of a program,No storage will be allocated for the const variable which are defined...It will just simply placed in the list created by compiler like macros.

In my case I am trying to take the adress of that constant variable .... So this is where Compiler will allocate some storage for that variable.

and It is an undefined behaviour indeed....
So what do you mean by "directly"?
 directly from where?
you mean to say directly from the list which was created by compiler for defined constant variables?

Comment: @Ankitsinghkushwah For constants of native types (int, float, etc) the compiler will frequently not allocate specific storage for the value but utilize the value directly in code (which is why you can use `const int` values as array sizes or in case statements).  Since you're taking the address of the constant variable the compiler will have to allocate some storage for it, but that storage may be in a read-only section of memory.  By "directly" I meant that the compiler will pass `3.1415926535` to `cout` rather than the value of `PIE`.